# How are these check-marks being drawn?

Tags: css

I was reading about pseudo-elements in the MDN reference site for CSS, and in the [article about `::before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore), they use a simple to-do list as an example. Its code is as follows:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Buy milk</li>
  <li>Take the dog for a walk</li>
  <li>Exercise</li>
  <li>Write code</li>
  <li>Play music</li>
  <li>Relax</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2em;
  background: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li.done {
  background: #CCFF99;
}

li.done::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #009933;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0.3em 0.25em 0;
  height: 1em;
  top: 1.3em;
  left: 0.6em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 0.5em;
}
```

Javascript

```
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if( ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
     ev.target.classList.toggle('done'); 
  }
}, false);
```

I get what the Javascript code does, and I was expecting that the check-mark would be images, but they're drawn by the CSS code. I can see where are the instructions about what and how to draw it, but I can't understand these instructions.

I also didn't know how to google about it (because I don't know the name of this technic in CSS), so I really got stuck here. How does it work?

Comment: I doubt that the rotating angle should be `45deg`, not `135deg`.

Comment: It is giving a border to the right and bottom and rotating it, and dimensions such that the height is higher then the width.  The rotation turns a backwards L into a checkmark.

Comment: Thank you @KingKing, it was originally 45, I was changing the values to see if I'd figure something out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li.done::before { /* This creates a (pseudo) element that is (by default) placed before the content, but is hidden (by default). */
  content: ''; /* This makes this (pseudo) element actually appear. */
  position: absolute; /* This makes it not push the content or affect it in anyway and also makes it act as if it has some sort of display: inline-block; */

  /* These create a right and bottom border and give a width and a height (width * 2) to this (pseudo) element, so you get a reversed L shape. */
  border-color: #009933; /* 
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0.3em 0.25em 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 0.5em;

  /* These position this (pseudo) element relatively to its real/owner element, the LI, since it has position: relative. */
  top: 1.3em;
  left: 0.6em;
  margin-top: -1em;

  /* This rotates this (pseudo) element. When you rotate a reversed L, it looks like a check mark. */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the relative positioning, please? What do you mean by "real element"?

Comment: The real element is the `<li>`. It has `position: relative` which makes the `top` and the `left` properties of an absolutely positioned (pseudo or not) element apply relatively to the `<li>` instead of relatively to the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

The `li.done::before` rule is creating a blank box essentially (`content: '';`), then styling the right and bottom margins (`0 0.3em 0.25em 0;`) and then rotating it 45 degrees (`transform: rotate(45deg);`) to make a check mark.